# Angular component not showing template

Tags: angular

I downloaded angular form https://angular.io/quick-start and then added a file to the app folder `tutoriel.component.ts` and wrote the following code

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: 'tutoriel',
    template: '<h2>Tutoriel</h2>'
})
export class TutorielComp{
    
}
```

and then changed this in the app.module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TutorielComp
  ],
```

and the class got imported `import { TutorielComp } from './tutoriel.component';` The problem is when I deleted all the code in the app.component.html and wrote

`<tutoriel></tutoriel>`

But,It did not show.
Edit: This is my Module file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TutorielComp } from './tutoriel.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TutorielComp
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Do you have "bootstrap: [AppComponent]" in your NgModule?

Comment: Yes,there is if you want I'll edit my question to show the Module file

Comment: can you check your link (go to a component that it's not related to your question)? BTW, when we add a new component, sometimes we need "reinit" the server: `ng serve`